# Is it possible to have multiple enctypes on an html form?

Tags: php, html, computer-science, web-development-server

I'm very new to any web development issues and I couldn't find a solution to this problem. I have a form for uploading files so I use the enctype="multipart/form-data". However, I was also trying to take the fields from the form and encode them in a JSON file and read those out in a table in my html on my webpage. With the default enctype, the JSON encoding works great but obviously the file upload functionality doesn't work and vice versa. I followed a lot of W3Schools tutorials but I'm still lost. Is it possible to use two enctypes or what is the work around to this problem? I'm only uploading my files to localhost, no databases used. I apologize if I give too much info here but my form html looks like:

```
<form class="modal-content animate" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

<div class="imgcontainer">

    <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>

</div>

<div class="container">

    <label for="artist"><b>Artist Name</b></label>

    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter name of artist" name="artist" required>

    <label for="song"><b>Song Name</b></label>

    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter name of song." name="song" required>
                    
    <label for="instrument"><b>Instrument Type</b></label>

    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter type of instrument for tab." name="instrument" required>
                    
    <label for="myfile"><b>Tablature</b></label>

    <input class="form-control" type="file" placeholder="Select your file." name="myfile" id="myfile" required>
                    
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload Tab PDF" class="w3-hover-purple" style="color:black; background-color:#A9A9A9"></input>
</div>

<div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">

    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>

</div>

</form>
```

My php code is structured as such:

```
<?php
  $message = '';
  $error = '';
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
      if(empty($_POST["artist"])) {
          $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter artist</label>";
      }
      else if(empty($_POST["song"])) {
          $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter song name</label>";
      }
      else if(empty($_POST["instrument"])) {
          $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter instrument</label>";
      }
      else if(empty($_POST["myfile"])) {
          $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter file to upload</label>";
      }
      else {
          if(file_exists('tablature.json')) {
              $current_data = file_get_contents('tablature.json');
              $array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);
              $extra = array(
                'artist'     => $_POST['artist'],
                'song'       => $_POST['song'],
                'instrument' => $_POST['instrument'],
                'myfile'     => $_POST['myfile']
              );
              $array_data[] = $extra;
              $final_data = json_encode($array_data);
              if(file_put_contents('tablature.json', $final_data)) {
                  $message = "<label class='text-success'>File Appended Successfully.</label>";
              }
              else {
                  $error = 'JSON File does not exist';
              }
          }
      }

  $target_dir = "Tablature/";
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
  $uploadOk = 1;
  $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
 
  // Check if file already exists
  if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $error = "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
  // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
  if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    $error = "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
  // if everything is ok, try to upload file
  } else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
      $message = "The file has been uploaded.";
    } else {
      $error = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
  }
  }
?>
```

Finally, on my page I print out my JSON contents on my page like so:

```
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Artist</th>
            <td>Song Name</td>
            <td>Instrument Type</td>
            <td style="float:right; margin-right:100px;">File</td>
        </tr>

<?php
        $read_data = file_get_contents("tablature.json");
        $read_data = json_decode($read_data, true);
        print("Working<br>");
        foreach($read_data as $row) {
        print('<tr><th><a href="#">'.$row["artist"].'</a></th><td><a href="#">'.$row["song"].'</a></td><td><a href="#">'.$row["instrument"].'</a></td><td style="float:right"><a href="#">'.$row["myfile"].'</a></td></tr>');
                  }
                ?>

    </table><br>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since POST is an array, you could "stringify" to json. Via `json_encode()`. You could return this value to the front-end.